# Using Python Classes to print a bracketed expression

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop, recursion

The expression is given as such:

```
e = Plus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5))
```

if I print(e) it should give me:

```
print(e)
(3+4)+5
```

My code is this, my logic is that for parent class value of prec is 0 so that when the class is evaluating inner Plus it should introduce '( )' as shown in the if-statment. Kindly correct my code. I am beginner here.

```
class Expr:
  prec=0
  def __str__(self):
    if self.prec>prec:
      return "("+str(self.l)+self.op+str(self.r)+")"
    else:
      return str(self.l) + self.op + str(self.r)


class Plus(Expr) :
  op='+'
  prec=1
  def __init__(self,l,r) :
    self.l = l
    self.r = r

class Const(Expr) :
  def __init__(self,v) :
    self.v = v

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.v)

e = Plus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5))

print(e)
#(3+4)+5
```

Comment: Can you share what error you get and what your code produces?

Comment: line 4, in __str__
    if self.prec>prec:
NameError: name 'prec' is not defined

Comment: I’m on mobile so I can’t type it all out for you, but please read some more about python Classes and Inheritance (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp). First of all you should only define properties in the __init__ function of a Class outside. Second you try to acces child properties in the Expression class and that can’t be done so you’ll have to figure out a different construction. I encourage you to read the w3 schools page and build on that.

Comment: you didn't define self.prec yet

Comment: I defined self.prec in my class(Expr) through def __init__ but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `prec` should be a parameter passed to the `__str__` function.

```py
class Expr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prec = 0
        self.nb_operands = 0
    def __str__(self, prec=0):
        if self.nb_operands == 0:
            return str(self.v)
        elif self.nb_operands == 1:
            return self.op + self.v.__str__(self.prec)
        elif self.nb_operands == 2:
            if self.prec < prec:
                return ''.join([
                    "(",
                    self.l.__str__(self.prec),
                    self.op,
                    self.r.__str__(self.prec),
                    ")"
                ])
            else:
                return self.op.join((
                    self.l.__str__(self.prec),
                    self.r.__str__(self.prec)
                ))

class Plus(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,l,r) :
        self.op = '+'
        self.prec = 1
        self.nb_operands = 2
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

class Times(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,l,r) :
        self.op = '*'
        self.prec = 2
        self.nb_operands = 2
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

class Minus(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,v) :
        self.op = '-'
        self.prec = 5
        self.nb_operands = 1
        self.v = v

class Const(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,v) :
        self.prec = 0
        self.v = v
        self.nb_operands = 0
```

Testing:

```py
print( Plus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5)) )
3+4+5

print( Plus(Times(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5)) )
3*4+5

print( Times(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5)) )
(3+4)*5

print( Times(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Minus(Const(5))) )
(3+4)*-5

print( Times(Minus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4))),Const(5)) )
-(3+4)*5
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. `Minus` as used here is more like unary `Negate` and should have a high precedence. Consider `Times(Minus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4))),Const(5))` should print `-(3+4)*5`

Comment: @Mulan You're absolutely right! I edited to give Minus a precedence of 5 and to add your example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to @Stef's terrific answer. I wanted to show a way to keep the class code simple while maintaining the elegance of her/his recursive process -

```py
class Expr:
  def __init__(self):
    self.prec = 0
    self.nb_operands = 0
  def __str__(self):
    return to_str(self)   # keep classes simple
```

Where `to_str` is defined as an ordinary function. Avoiding over a dozen instances of `self` and manual calls to `__str__` improves readability -

```py
def to_str(e, prec=0):
  match e.nb_operands: 
    case 0:
      return str(e.v)
    case 1:
      return e.op + to_str(e.v, e.prec)
    case 2:
      if e.prec < prec:
        return ''.join([
          "(",
          to_str(e.l, e.prec),
          e.op,
          to_str(e.r, e.prec),
          ")"
        ])
      else:
        return e.op.join([
          to_str(e.l, e.prec),
          to_str(e.r, e.prec)
        ])
```